# proof two matrices are positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $M$ is a symmetric matrix and $M=N^2$, $NM=MN$, then how do I prove:

$M$ is positive definite $\iff N$ is positive definite?

I know $M$ is positive definite if $x^TMx >0 $, and  I should probably get $x^TMx = \cdots =x^TNx$ but I don't know how to get there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that $M = N^2$ is sufficient to conclude $MN = NM$, so you need not put the latter as a hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. It is true that if $N$ is positive definite, then $M$ is positive definite. However, the converse does not hold. For example, consider
$$
N = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&2}, \quad M = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\0 & 4}.
$$
Verify that we indeed have $M = N^2$ (and as a consequence, $NM = MN$) and $M$ is indeed positive definite. However, it is not true that $N$ is positive definite.

Comment: $N=M^2$ here${}{}$.

Comment: @Martund Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: I think you also need to change your second statement now.

Comment: @Martund I don't see what you mean

Comment: You yourself are contradicting the second statement of your answer. $M$ is positive definite, but $N$ is not.

Comment: @Martund I see now, fixed.